# Powershell Check Current Date And Folder Modified Date

Tags: powershell, shell, date, validation, command-line

Looking for a way to check both the current date and a certain folders last modified date both against a set end date.

The below checks for the current date against a start and end date:

```
if ($today -ge $startdate -and $today -le $enddate) {
    Write-Output "Run script"
}else{
    Write-Output "Date out of range"
}
```

I need something like "If current date OR Folder last modified date is after "Set Date" write expired"
Have not been able to figure out how to combine these.
Please help!

EDIT:
So far have come up with this:
`$Modified = $($(ls 'C:\test.txt').LastWriteTime -gt $enddate);`
But the above only works for files, not folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get-ChildItem CmdLet

`ls` is an alias for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdLet.

- Running `ls` (or `gci`/`Get-ChildItem`) on a file gives the attributes of the file, returning a single Item.
- Running `ls` (or `gci`/`Get-ChildItem`) on a folder gives the attributes of the contents of the folder, returning an array of Items.

So, `$(ls C:\temp).LastWriteTime` returns output like this, a list of datetimes for all items in the folder:

```
$(gci c:\temp).LastWriteTime

Tuesday, 1 October 2019 10:23:02 AM
Monday, 4 November 2019 2:06:56 PM
Wednesday, 7 August 2019 2:55:32 PM
Thursday, 10 October 2019 3:42:06 PM
...
```

Which cannot be meaningfully compared using `-gt` and does not refer to the `LastWriteTime` of the intended folder.

### Get-Item CmdLet

To ensure you get `LastWriteTime` for the singular item, whether it's a file or folder, use `gi`/`Get-Item` instead.

#### Folder

```
$(gi c:\temp).LastWriteTime

Tuesday, 18 June 2019 9:30:11 AM
```

#### File

```
$(gi C:\temp\pinglog.txt).LastWriteTime

Tuesday, 20 August 2019 5:20:06 PM
```

Comment: Terrible comment etiquette for SO, but thank you too. I've been waiting months to get above 4K reputation! Happy weekend!